# Updating a field with one from another database where a field matches in both

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to update all the prices in one database with the prices from another where the product code matches (which isn't the primary key), whilst leaving the other fields columns untouched.

```
INSERT INTO inventory
SELECT * FROM temporary_table
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE price = VALUES(price)
```

This is just duplicating the whole product where the code matches

Thanks in advance

Comment: `INSERT` is not a good way to `UPDATE` data.

Comment: Consider providing a sqlfiddle of same.

Answer (score 0):

Try using replace instead of insert. select all the columns from inventory table except the one you want to update(price)

```
REPLACE INTO inventory
SELECT b.col1, b.col2......... a.price 
FROM temporary_table a, inventory b
where a.product_code = b.product_code
```